# how to maintain application scope in Tomcat clustering?

Tags: java, tomcat, scope, tomcat6, cluster-computing

I have configured the `load balancing` and the `Clustering` with `Tomcat 6` in multiple machines and my `Java` application is deployed in all machines.

This works fine for me to maintain and to share the `session objects` between the `servers`.

But how to share and maintain the `hash maps` between the `tomcat servers` when any one of the `tomcat` gets down.

Is it possible to do this , or any other suggestions ?

Good answers are definitely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's no application scope replication in any of the servers I know.

Why do you want to replicate the application scope anyway?

Generally only application configurations details will be put in the application. So replicating this in my opinion have no valid use case.

Comment: In some cases I need to get some values around the application which has been changable.

Comment: You are better off using a distributed cache in that case for values like that. If you want to replicate application scope variables you will have to roll out something on your own..

Answer (score 0):

Use database or some other storage for application scoped object.